# How can i only show mods?

Tags: css

I want to show only mods and I need to `display:none;` to the user class. Could you please help me?

I've tried this code:

```
.Message_1P-Ez .react-contextmenu-wrapper .messageBody_edDIz .top_3RPvk .chatLabel_1LP_p.mod_28jZF { display:none;}
```

Mods has this (user don't have this):

```
.Message_1P-Ez .react-contextmenu-wrapper .messageBody_edDIz .top_3RPvk .chatLabel_1LP_p.mod_28jZF
```

Both have this:

```
.Message_1P-Ez .react-contextmenu-wrapper .messageBody_edDIz .top_3RPvk
```

We need to hide users in `.Message_1P-Ez`. How can I do it? Can i use `:has`? I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: Message_1P-Ez is used in both mods and users? Your question is not clear. First you say Mods has this(user dont have this): Message_1P-Ez and after that you say Both have this: .Message_1P-Ez.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use the opposite of `:has()`, which is `:not()`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not